# how to get data between dates

Tags: sql

I have following table with data:

```
id  startdate   finishdate
4   2015-09-17  2016-09-28
5   2016-08-17  2016-09-12
```

Now i need data for this date -  `2016-02-02`

For example if i enter this date `2016-02-02` then only 1st data will display.

Now if i enter date - `2016-08-10` then it will display both data.

i have tried with :

```
  select * from customer where startdate >='2016-02-02' or finishdate<='2016-02-02'
```

but it is not working.

how can i achieve this ?

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Add back the tag for the database you are really using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your logic is simply backwards:

```
select c.*
from customer c
where startdate <= '2016-02-02' and finishdate >= '2016-02-02';
```

I advise you not to use `between` for dates.  [Here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) is a really good explanation by Aaron Bertrand on why that is a bad idea.

Comment: I'm not sure why discouraging people from using BETWEEN needed to be part of this answer.  Many of the criticisms in the comments at the end of the explanation by Aaron Bertrand are perfectly valid reasons why his view of BETWEEN is unwarranted.